# I can access my wifi router 192.168.0.1 but NOT my modem router 192.168.1.1

Tags: router, modem

Well for a while now (few weeks) I cannot access my modem router by typing 192.168.1.1 on internet browser.

[image]

I am surfing on internet through my wifi router and I can access 192.168.0.1 but not 192.168.1.1

Before I didn’t have this problem and I was able to access both 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.0.1 to make any changes that I wanted.

Do you have any clue what is causing this problem for me? Both modem router and wifi router are shown in Advanced IP scanner program  when I scan the network.

When I ping 192.168.1.1 everything seems to be in order

I am thankful for any help/advice I can get.

Comment: Does the wifi router has dhcp activated itself?

Comment: Did you try simply rebooting the router(s) yet?

Comment: Answer to Mikaso: YES DHCP is activated on wifi router. See the link http://prntscr.com/8h4ll4 Answer to Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 ; Well I did reboot my wifi router (192.168.0.1) but not modem router (192.168.1.1) And thanks again for your quick respond.

Comment: if you didnt do any recent changes(Topology ones and settings ones), maybe your ISP close the internal access to the Modem.

Comment: If you do `ipconfig` from the command line on your computer what is listed as `IPv4Address`, `Subnet Mask`, and `Default Gateway`?

Comment: This is what I get. I posted both what cmd is showing and Advanced IP scanner  http://prntscr.com/8hae81

Answer (score -2):

Check on the router to verify that the IP of the modem has not updated. It could be as simple as it having picked up a new lease.

Comment: I agree: ensure it didn't get reset to factory (etc). Alternatively, reset it to factory and reconfigure it.  I usually set the wifi device to a static IP on the "regular" subnet outside the range of assignable DHCP addresses, and turn off DHCP. The device will act as an AP but allow the other router to actually handle the DHCP assignments.